# How to deploy MSI on a network without actually installing it

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-installer, gpo

I need to deploy an executable through AD/GPO in an enterprise network. The executable needs to be run only once and it doesn't need to be actually installed.

I know that I need to build a MSI package to deploy my executable through AD/GPO, but I don't want the MSI to be actually installed as a setup file.

What's the best approach to deploy such kind of file and have MSI to delete everything and self-delete once the execution is over?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can this be accomplished by a login script rather than a AD/GPO? It seems like you are trying to use the wrong tool to simply copy an executable file to a target machine.